# $L^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1])$ has no cyclic vector for the multiplication operator

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}=L^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1])$ and $T=M_g\oplus M_g$ where $g(t)=t$ and $(M_gf)(t)=g(t)f(t)$. I want to verify that $\mathcal{H}$ has no cyclic vector for $T$.

The operator norm closure of all polynomials in $T$ is $\{M_\varphi\oplus M_\varphi:\varphi\in C([0,1])\}$. Suppose $(f,g)\in\mathcal{H}$ is cyclic for $T$, I want to show that $\{(\varphi f,\varphi g): \varphi\in C([0,1])\}$ is not dense in $\mathcal{H}$. How do I proceed?

Edit: Is the following correct?

Suppose $\mathcal{A}=\{(\varphi f,\varphi g): \varphi\in C([0,1])\}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\mathcal{A}^\perp=\{0\}$. However $(\bar{g},-\bar{f})\in\mathcal{A}^\perp$ and hence $f$ and $g$ are zero almost everywhere, which clearly contradicts that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: If $(f,g)$ is a cyclic vector for $T=M_\varphi\oplus M_\varphi$ then the linear span of $T^n(f,g)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}.$ As you observed the element $(\overline{g},-\overline{f})$ is orthogonal to all elements $T^n(f,g).$